# How does IDENTITY not equal record number in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have been doing some testing of script performance (adding start and end times to a `RunTimeStats` table). I have a column called `ID` which is defined as `INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)`.

I wanted to delete all rows after the 7th row to remove the timestamps associated with some partially completed records which were generated when some new scripts failed to complete, so I ran the following command:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.RunTimeStats
WHERE ID > 7
```

I have noticed that when I update this table with new records, the ID column no longer equals the record number for records 8 onwards.

Please can someone explain how the identity value can get out of sync from the actual SQL record number?

Also, I plan to start using transactions to avoid this going forward!

Comment: `IDENTITY` is not suited to your purpose if you need no gaps. It does not guarantee this at all. And transactions won't make any difference. Why do you care about gaps?.

Comment: After deleting records identity values not reset.

Answer (score 5):

An `IDENTITY` is just an **arbitirary** number, it has nothing to do with the number of rows in the table. The seed on an `IDENTITY` will increment *every* time an `INSERT` is attempted. When you `DELETE` a row, rows with a greater value for the `IDENTITY` than the row the was deleted won't get updated to b e a lower number.

The reason you aren't getting everything apart from the "first 7" rows is because the value of `ID` and the "row number" aren't the same.

From [IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15):

> ### Remarks
>
> Identity columns can be used for generating key values. The identity property on a column guarantees the following:
>
> - Each new value is generated based on the current seed & increment.
> - Each new value for a particular transaction is different from other concurrent transactions on the table.
>
> The identity property on a column does not guarantee the following:
>
> - Uniqueness of the value - Uniqueness must be enforced by using a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint or UNIQUE index.
> - Consecutive values within a transaction - A transaction inserting multiple rows is not guaranteed to get consecutive values for the rows
>     because other concurrent inserts might occur on the table. If values
>     must be consecutive then the transaction should use an exclusive lock
>     on the table or use the SERIALIZABLE isolation level.
> - Consecutive values after server restart or other failures -SQL Server might cache identity values for performance reasons and some of
>     the assigned values can be lost during a database failure or server
>     restart. This can result in gaps in the identity value upon insert. If
>     gaps are not acceptable then the application should use its own
>     mechanism to generate key values. Using a sequence generator with the
>     NOCACHE option can limit the gaps to transactions that are never
>     committed.
> - Reuse of values - For a given identity property with specific seed/increment, the identity values are not reused by the engine. If a
>     particular insert statement fails or if the insert statement is rolled
>     back then the consumed identity values are lost and will not be
>     generated again. This can result in gaps when the subsequent identity
>     values are generated.

If you want to do this, you would be better off with something like `ROW_NUMBER` or `OFFSET`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT ID,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS RN
   FROM dbo.RunTimeStats)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 7;

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ID
    FROM dbo.RunTimeStats
    ORDER BY ID OFFSET 7 ROWS)
DELETE FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the rows doesn't reseed the identity values. On the other hand when a table is truncated, the identity column is reseeded to 1 in this case. Or you can manually reseed using the below statement,

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TABLE_NAME', RESEED, 1)